# How to access parent hidden field value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I need help accessing a parent hidden input value so I can use it to render some child data.

I know how to render HTML using Jquery but I don't know how to access the hidden field to then use it's value to render the child data.

**Here's my code:**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/ShoppingCartWS.asmx/GetPackagesV2",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (result) {
  var data = eval("(" + result.d + ")");
  if (data.status == 0) {

      var packageTable = '<div id="packageAccordion">';
      var numbers = getSelectedNumbers();

      for (var j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
      packageTable += '<input type="hidden" id="hfID'+ numbers[j].numberId +'" value="' + numbers[j].PrefixId + '" />';

         // renders HTML numbers information

      for (var i = 0; i < data.packages.length; i++) {

         // Needs to render HTML based on the hidden field value above...
      }
      }
      $('#packageTableContainer').html(packageTable);
    } 
else 
    {
        //Display Error
    }
  }
});
```

I was thinking of accessing the hidden value by using the code snippet below but I don't know how to incorporate it into the above code?

```
 $("[id^=hfID]").val();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
// mimics your numbers variable
var number = {id: parseInt(1), type: "fit"};

// getting the value for the hidden input
var name = $("#my"+ number.id).val();

//populated that value
$("div").text(name);
```